# Would you elaborate between have been v-ing and have p.p.?

Tags: grammar

> I have flown to Toronto a great deal this month.
>
> I have been flying to Toronto a great deal this month.

Would you possibly explain the different between them?

Comment: I have noticed you posting a few topics of this nature on this site.  I would recommend that many of them would be better suited for the [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](http://ell.stackexchange.com).  They're not inappropriate here, but in many cases you may get an answer that is suited toward simpler usage and not diatribes on grammatical oddities.

Comment: Additionally, I might change *a great deal* to *many times*.  People definitely use *a great deal*, but it's not quite the right terminology.  It means to a large degree.  As in, *I had a great deal of difficulty answering this question.*

Comment: The OP **has asked** a grand total of 38 questions; many patient users on ELU **have been writing, explaining, and answering** these questions; but the OP **has not awarded** one answer yet.

Comment: A: I haven't seen you in ages, how come? B: I've been flying to Toronto a lot recently. A: I see... are you flying again this week? B: Possibly, it depends on my boss.

Comment: Hi. Nima. Can I talk with you in chat room? Please answer me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is something likely to set off a debate about how many tenses English has, etc.

The first construction:  *I have flown* is the present perfect.  It is semantically equivalent to *I flew* (the simple past tense).

The second construction:  *I have been flying* is the present perfect progressive (or present perfect continuous).  It is semantically equivalent to *I flew* but adds a sense of *And, I have been doing it quite a bit* -or- *And, I am continuing to do so*.  In other words, this construction would typically be used to convey the sense that you are heading to Toronto *again*, and you've been doing it a lot this month!

The meaning of both are fairly equivalent.  But, the subtext is ever so slightly different.

Just as a disclaimer.  You *can* use both interchangeably, few will fault you for it.  But, many people will read the subtext there whether it exists or not.

Comment: I disagree that *I have been flying* implies that I will be going to Toronto again. In my mind the constructions are equivalent in meaning but the second emphasizes the great amount of time spent flying, while the first emphasizes just the number of trips.

Comment: I'm just a native speaker but "I've been flying to Toronto a great deal this month" does not imply a new trip. Is there an implied "in comparison with other months"? Not with the sentence standing by itself. I qualified my comment but still was downvoted, alas.

Comment: @user26732 Your comment was likely down voted because of the lack of explanation.  (It wasn't me.  I always comment.)

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus Yeah . . . I hear you.  It's subtle and can be read both ways.  It definitely gives a sense of continuity to the whole thing, though.  Perhaps on-going was the wrong choice of terminology.  And, yeah I goofed on the tense!  In my head I was reading it as *had flown*.

Comment: An answer without an explanation is still an answer. Often the reasons to an English question answer are extraordinarily complex and stating the reason doesn't really help. In American English, a full stop always precedes the final quotation mark. In British English, it's the opposite. This can be said in two sentences. The reasons for the difference would take a chapter at least. And for some questions, the real reasons for the answers are unknown. Does the greater use of the subjunctive tense in Spanish rather than in English mean that English speakers are more certain of their future?

Comment: @user26732 Welcome to Stack Exchange.  The most up voted answers here have quality explanations attached.  One line answers are often down voted out of hand.  Again, I didn't down vote you, so I cannot defend it.

Comment: I've been on SE for a long time now, just not the English forum. In  the forum I am most familiar with, if someone asks how to load a package in a program, one line correct answers are very helpful. I guess not so much here.

Comment: @user26732 Yes.  This particular SE is *VERY* persnickety about explanations.

Answer (score 1):

The first example, *have flown*, is fully in the past, even tough the delimiter is *this month*. it gives no sense of any ongoing activity from the present moment.

The second example, *have been flying*, describes past events, but the progressive gives the sense of an ongoing activity. While it does not explicitly indicate that the activity will continue, there is the sense that it may well be ongoing.

Consider stripped down examples:

> I have flown to Toronto.
>
> I have been flying to Toronto.

The first sentence suggests one event which is over with no sense of any more happening.  The second connotes more than one event and the implication that it may well be ongoing.

In many circumstances, either original sentence would work. But the context would dictate if one is better than the other.

> I have flown to Toronto a great deal this month. *I'm glad that is over.*
>
> I have been flying to Toronto a great deal this month. *I wonder when this whirlwind pace will end.*

Answer (score -3):

In terms of meaning they are synonyms and can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Considering that an upvoted post (and more than one comment) agreed with my point that these sentences are semantically equivalent, I don't think a downvote is appropriate.